# Finding paths that cover every node once in weighted directed graph (any language)

Tags: graph-algorithm

I have a directed, weighted graph.  It may or may not be connected, and the components may or may not be connected as well.  I have two goals:

1. At the very least, come up with a list of paths (may have to be combination of paths if entire graph is not connected) that visits every node once and only once.
2. If possible, find the shortest path (or combination of paths in the case that the graph is not connected) that visits every node once and only once.

Currently, I'm thinking the simplest way would just be to find all of the connected components (using dfs, right?) and then within each component recurse through every possible choice of node and sort through the paths that I'm left with to find the shortest one.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly as you said, I would start discovering the connected components using BFS and inside each graph you can apply TSP(Traveling Salesman Problem) algorithm.

You can find enought details about the algorithm on [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)